How to get FileSystemDirectoryHandle using a FileSystemFileHandle
I am trying to select a file using showOpenFilePicker and once a file is selected, I want to get the directory(FileSystemDirectoryHandle) of where the selected file is located. I want to get the directory data in background without opening the directory picker. Is that even possible?
Getting the file handle
const [fileHandle] = await (window as any).showOpenFilePicker({
    types: [
      {
        description: 'ABCD Files',
        accept: {
          'application/vnd.yourapp.abcd': ['.abcd'],
        },
      },
    ],
  })

Without opening the directory picker, how can i get the directory of the parent folder which the selected file is located.
So instead of this to get the directory
const directoryHandle = await (window as any).showDirectoryPicker()

How to use the fileHandle to get the directory handle?

why do you need such access from your web page to someone elses computer?

my app can open a specific project. I should be able to just select the main project file, instead of the project folder to open the project.

You can ask them to select a folder containing a project file. You'll get a list of File objects contained in that folder and all its subfolders. Next, you can filter this list of Files and do with them as you please. For example, you can skip all intermediate files and read / load only source files.
